Org-mode babel shell async evaluation not working with named sessions
I'm trying to use shell asynchronously with named sessions, but it doesn't work:
#+begin_src sh
  echo "a"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: a

#+begin_src sh :async
  echo "a"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: a

#+begin_src sh :session s1
  echo "a"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: a

#+begin_src sh :session s1 :async
  echo "a"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 7adf9461-2964-48b3-9c90-2ffecfd593be

#+begin_src sh :session :async
  echo "a"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: a


As you can see, everything works till I combine a named session with async.
A session without a name doesn't maintain variables, etc. So it doesn't work for my use-case.
I've tried with zsh and bash, but they don't change anything.
In theory, it should work, as seen in the tutorial

Please provide version info. I suspect it was a bug that was fixed more recently than your org mode version. In particular, it works for me on (more-or-less) bleeding-edge Org mode.

Edit: actually it also seems to work fine in 9.6.15 which was released with Emacs 29.4 I believe, so I'm not sure how recent the fix (if any) might be. So please provide version info (both for Emacs and for Org mode).

The problem solved itself after restarting emacs.
I think it might have been a problem with elpaca, because if I didn't install ob-async myself it wouldn't work.
